# How to verify cookies from Nextjs UI to an external server Nodejs Server

Tags: node.js, rest, cookies, next.js

I have been struggling for days with no success with my web application. The kind of similar questions on stake overflow are not addressing my issue. I have a standalone Nodejs server which is basically an API provider and a standalone Nextjs web app which serves as the UI. The idea is to have them different Servers in production. On localhost the Next app is running on port 3000 and the Node App is running on port 5000. I am trying to do authentication but how can I verify cookies from the browser (Nextjs App) on the Server. When a user logs in the server sends the user data and a token in a cookie. The cookie is then saved on the browser, from here how can I send back that cookie to the server for verification from Nextjs.

Here is my backend code (Nodejs App running at port 5000)

```
  const signToken = (id) =>
     jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
     expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true,
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;
  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;
  user.passwordChangedAt = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};



exports.Login = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  //1) Check if email and password exists
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password!', 400));
  }
  //2) Check if user exists && password is correct
  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

  if (!user || !(await user.correctPassword(password, user.password))) {
    return next(new AppError('Incorrect email or password', 401));
  }
  //3) If everything is ok , send token to client
  createSendToken(user, 200, res);
});
```

Frontend Code (Nextjs App running on port 3000)

```
const postData = async (url, post, token) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${serverUrl}${url}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: token,
      },
      
      body: JSON.stringify(post),
     
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

   const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const res = await postData('users/login', userData);
        console.log(res);
        if(res.status === 'fail') return  errorAlert(res.message)
         successAlert('Login Successful')

        dispatch({ type: 'AUTH', payload: {
          token: res.token,
          user: res.user,
          cookie: cookieData
        }})

        Cookie.set('token', res.token)
        localStorage.setItem('firstLogin', true)
    };
```

Comment: _"have them different Servers in production"_ - are the Next.js app and the Node.js server on the same domain in production?

Comment: @juliomalves, I am planning to have the server running at subdomain **https://dash:example.com** and the UI on the domain **https://example.com**.  I tried to read this article _https://medium.com/@zhamdi/next-js-as-a-frontend-talking-to-a-backend-server-how-to-manage-authentication-276b29c03474_ but i have not used graphql and I am using REST API

Answer (score 0):

The cookie which you set after authentication in the browser is included by the browser for subsequent requests to Nextjs server automatically.

You can verify this by checking the req/res in Network Tab.

In Nextjs, we can have a function for validation:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

const TOKEN = '<token-name>';

const isRequestValid = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const cookie = req.cookies[TOKEN]

  if (!cookie) {
    return false;
  }

  // validate cookie here by sending request to Node server (running on 5000)
  // and return true or false
  return ...
}
```

Then create a _middleware.tsx under `pages`. Here we will define our `_middleware` function.
This would run on every req (since it's defined at the root level. More on [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware))

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  // check for authenticated routes
  if (pathname === '<path-for-which-you-want-to-authenticate>') {
    if (!isRequestValid(req)) {
      return NextResponse.redirect('<url-for-redirection-if-not-authenticated>')
    }

  }

  // if user is authenticated this will be called which continues the
  // normal flow of application
  return NextResponse.next()
}
```